# Input When Converted To An Integer Is Out Of Range

Tags: python

say I have this following code:

```
command = input("prompt :> ").strip().lower()
try:
    command = command.split()
# My input will be something like AB 1 2
    x = int(command[1])-1
    y = int(command[2])-1
    if command[0] == "ab":
       A_to_B(heights[x],distances[y])
```

Where heights is a list of lists and so is distance:

```
heights = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6']]
distances = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
```

So I input AC 1 2

```
x = 0
y = 1
```

Then I'll pluck the list at the 0 index from heights, and the list at the 1 index from distances. However I keep running into a IndexError:list out of range. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

For simplicity's sake I changed quite a bit of the names in the code above.

Here's what my actual A_to_B function looks like

```
def tableau_to_foundation(tab, fnd):
    '''Determines if movements from the tableaus to the foundations are    valid.'''
    if len(tab) == 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Your tableau is empty.")
    src_card = tab[-1]
    dest_card = None
    valid_fnd_move(src_card, dest_card)
    fnd.append(tab.pop())
```

And here's valid_fnd_move(src_card, dest_card)

```
def valid_fnd_move(src_card, dest_card):
    '''Determines if the initial moves done to the foundation are valid. '''
    #First Check for when foundation is empty 
    if dest_card == None and src_card.rank() == 1:
        return 
    #Second Check for when foundation is empty 
    if dest_card == None and src_card.rank() != 1:
        raise RuntimeError("You need to place an ace into the foundation first.")
    #Checks if foundation is not empty 
    if not dest_card.suit() == src_card.suit() and \
       src_card.rank == dest_card.rank() + 1:
        raise RuntimeError("You can only place cards of the same suit together in a particular foundation")
```

Comment: Not sure if that has anything to do with your IndexError but you have a typo in line 4 `y = int(command[2])-1`

Comment: My index error is still there but thanks for the catch

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Oh I did split it I forget to write it into the question

Comment: the code you paste won't cause IndexError if `x==0` and `y==1`. What is the implementation of `A_to_B`?

Comment: @RGPython: Can you provide the exact error and traceback? This code looks fine once you added the `split`, assuming you're on Python 3 (are you?). If the traceback shows an error within `A_to_B` we need the implementation of `A_to_B` to help.

Comment: @stanleyli  I added the implementation of A_to_B above